# php conditional form validation by date

Tags: php

I have the function below that takes an entered date and serves  different validation messages base don the dates value .The thing is is not always working as it's supposed. I'm new at PHP and maybe i'm doing something wrong. Anyone has an ideea how to correct it?

```
function validate_date($result, $value, $form, $field){

$date1=date("Y", strtotime($value));
$date2=date("Y");
$diff= $date2-$date1;
$diff2=18-$diff;


if ($value ==0) { 
    $result["is_valid"] = false;
    $result["message"] = "Compeltati data!";
}
else {
    if ($diff < 0) { 
        $result["is_valid"] = false;
        $result["message"] = "Data invalida!";
    }
    elseif ($diff == 0) {
        $result["is_valid"] = false;
        $result["message"] ="Data invalida!";
    }
    elseif ($diff > 0){
        if ($diff2 > 0 and $diff2 < 5 ){
            $result["is_valid"] = true;
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Va trebuie confirmarea parintilor. Contactati-ne pe email!");</script>';
        }
        elseif ($diff2 > 5) {
            $result["is_valid"] = false;
            $result["message"] = "Nu aveti varsta minima pentru participare!";
        }
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

Comment: `"not always working as it's supposed."` Please be more specific - whats the result, what did you expect instead

Comment: `not always working as it's supposed.` is not an error message. Be more specific what doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't "elseif" be "else if" instead?

Comment: @Alex: Maybe in Javascript or even Java. But in PHP it's elseif.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Both forms are correct when using curly brackets, but only `elseif` would be alright in case of a colon: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php.

Comment: @Luka: I already thought both forms would work. I just didn't write my full thought.

Comment: Why do you serve `$form` and `$field` if it's never used in the function and what's not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand $diff is AGE and $diff2 is how much he/she is younger then 18year age. In that case if age of person is more then 18 then $diff2 will be negative and you have'nt added any clause for $diff2<0. so add it like:

`if ($diff2 > 0 and $diff2 < 5 ){
            $result["is_valid"] = true;
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Va trebuie confirmarea parintilor. Contactati-ne pe email!");</script>';
        }
        elseif ($diff2 > 5) {
            $result["is_valid"] = false;
            $result["message"] = "Nu aveti varsta minima pentru participare!";
        }
        else { //for $diff<=0
            $result["is_valid"] = false; //as you need change it on age >=18
            $result["message"] = "as you need!";
         }`